# Are default zones not pre-populated following a fresh install in firewalld?

Tags: centos, firewalld

CentOS 7 / Minimal Install

I want to get my feet wet with `firewalld` and am coming across some issues.

- I installed it via `yum install firewalld`
- I enabled it via `systemctl enable firewalld.service`
- I started it via `systemctl start firewalld.service`

My understanding is that at this point, it should have a pre-defined list of zones that I can later enable and add rules to. However if I run `firewall-cmd --get-zones` I get a blank output:

```
[foo@foo /] firewall-cmd --get-zones
[foo@foo /]
```

Do I need to create these zones manually?